# Convert elements of an array to be array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Is it possible to convert elements (string) of an array to be array?

For example:

```
a = ["hello", "world"]

result = [ ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"] , ["w", "o", "r", "l","d"] ]
```

Comment: `split()`. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/

Comment: Sure it is possible. You can create a `String[][]` array (often referred to as 2D but it's actually an array of arrays). Just try it. - If you don't know how then do some research, tell us what you've tried/researched and why you failed. Then we can help with specific problems.

Comment: yes it is possible, did you try anything yourself yet? Do you want to get an array of arrays of single-letter-strings (like your "result") or maybe an array of arrays of characters? (`{{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}, {'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'}}`)

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way I can see, whereas you can do something as below

```
    String a[] = {"hello", "world"};
    String result[][] = new String[a.length][];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        String[] strArray = a[i].split("");
        result[i] = strArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use java stream :

```
String[] array = {"hello", "world"};
Arrays.stream(array).map(a->a.split("")).map(sub->Arrays.asList(sub)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

output :

```
[h, e, l, l, o]
[w, o, r, l, d]
```